# Apply noise on circle according to mouseX and mouseY

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have created a blob with small points. I want my blob to show noise on its surface according to mouseX and mouseY. I want it to show high noise in the quadrant in which the mouse lies. I want it to be wavy. Below is my code.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var cx = 200;
var cy = 200;
var radius = 50;
var amp = 2;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

document.querySelector("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
 mouseX = e.clientX;
 mouseY = e.clientY;
});

function drawTheBlob() {
 ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  for (var a = 0; a < 360; a ++) {
    var angle = a * Math.PI/180;
    var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle) + Math.random() * amp;
    var y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle) + Math.random() * amp;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawTheBlob);
}

drawTheBlob();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adds a sin wave on the circle. Use `ctx.arc` to draw the flat part of the circle for speed as drawing many circles with lines will be slow. See code for comments on what is done.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
var cx = 100;
var cy = 100;
var radius = 50;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
const quadWidth = Math.PI / 2;     // area of effect PI/2 is 90 degree
const steps = radius / quadWidth; // number steps around the circle matches 1 pixel per step, 
const noiseAmpMax = 5;         // in pixels
const noiseWaveMoveSpeed = 2;  // speed of waves on circle in radians per second
const noiseWaveFreq = 16;      // how many waves per 360 deg
document.querySelector("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
});

function drawTheBlob(time) { // time is passed from the requestAnimationFrame call
  var amp = 0; // amplitude of noise 
  var wavePos = ((time / 1000) * Math.PI) * noiseWaveMoveSpeed;
  var mouseDir = Math.atan2(mouseY - cy, mouseX - cx);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  // draw arc for parts that have no noise as it is a log quicker
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, mouseDir + quadWidth / 2, mouseDir + Math.PI * 2 - quadWidth / 2);
  for (var a = 0; a < 1; a += 1 / steps) {
    var angle = (mouseDir - quadWidth / 2) + a * quadWidth;
    var angDist = Math.abs(angle - mouseDir); // find angular distance from mouse
                                              // as a positive value, it does not mater 
                                              // what the sign is
    if (angDist < quadWidth / 2) { // is angle distance within the range of effect
                                   // normalise the distance (make it 0 to 1)
      amp = 1 - angDist / (quadWidth / 2);
    } else {
      amp = 0; // no noise
    }
    // amp will be zero if away from mouse direction and 0 to 1 the closer to 
    // mouse angle it gets.
    // add a sin wave to the radius and scale it by amp
    var dist = radius + Math.sin(wavePos + noiseWaveFreq * angle) * noiseAmpMax * amp;
    var x = cx + dist * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = cy + dist * Math.sin(angle);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  ctx.closePath(); // use close path to close the gap (only needed if you need to draw a line from the end to the start. It is not needed to match beginPath
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(drawTheBlob);
}

requestAnimationFrame(drawTheBlob); // start this way so that you get the time argument
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

### How it works.

#### Mouse direction

First we need the direction from the circle to the mouse. To do that we use the function `Math.atan2` It takes the vector from the circle to the mouse and returns the direction in radians. The function is a little weird as it takes y first, then x.

```
var mouseDir = Math.atan2(mouseY - cy, mouseX - cx);
```

#### Draw arc to save CPU time

Now that we have the direction to the mouse we can draw the parts of the circle that has no noise using `arc` .

```
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, mouseDir + quadWidth / 2, mouseDir + Math.PI * 2 - quadWidth / 2);
```

The variable `quadWidth` is angular size of the noise bit so from the `mouseDir`  we add half that angular width and draw the arc around to `mouseDir`  plus 360deg take half the `quadWidth`.

#### Quick word on Radians

Almost all programming languages use radians to define angles, 360deg is equal to 2 * PI or 2 * 3.1415, which can be hard to get your head around, but there is good reason to use radians. For now just remember that a full circle in radians is `2 * Math.PI = 360deg`, `Math.PI = 180deg`, `Math.PI / 2 = 90deg`, `Math.PI / 4 = 45Deg` and `Math.PI / 180 = 1deg`. You dont have to remember the digits just `Math.PI` is half a circle.

`quadWidth` from above is a constant defined as `const quadWidth = Math.PI / 2;` which is 90deg.

#### The for loop

The for loop only draws the (Math.PI / 2) 90deg section around the `mouseDir`, from 45 deg left to 45 right. or whatever you set `quadWidth` to.

```
for (var a = 0; a < 1; a += 1 / steps) {
```

I loop from 0 to 1 the number of steps that give a reasonably smooth curve. We can find what part of the noisy arc we are drawing by multiplying the value `a * 
quadWidth` and adding that to the `mouseDir - quadWidth / 2`. This means that we start at `mouseDir - 45deg` and move clock wise to `mouseDir + 45deg`

```
var angle = (mouseDir - quadWidth / 2) + a * quadWidth;
```

Next i find how far that `angle` is from the `mouseDir` (could optimize it here a bit here but this way is a little more flexible, if you want to draw more noise on the other part of the arc)

```
var angDist = Math.abs(angle - mouseDir);
```

If that number is less than `quadWidth / 2` convert the value to the range 0 to 1 where 0 is at the angle furthest from the mouse direction and 1 closest.

```
if (angDist < quadWidth / 2) { 
    amp = 1 - angDist / (quadWidth / 2);
} else {
    amp = 0; 
}
```

#### The sin wave

Now we calculate the radius of the circle at the current angle and add a sin wave to it. First the `radius` then the sin wave multiplied by the `amp` calculated in the last step. Where `amp` is zero none of the sin wave is added, where `amp` is 1 (in the direction of the mouse) the full sin wave is added.

```
var dist = radius + Math.sin(wavePos + noiseWaveFreq * angle) * noiseAmpMax * amp
```

The values `wavePos`, `noiseWaveFreq`, and `noiseAmpMax` control the animation of the sin wave. Play around with these values to get a feel of what they do, `wavePos` is calculated based on the time at the start of the function.

With `dist` we can calculate the x,y position for the next line of the circle

```
var x = cx + dist * Math.cos(angle);
var y = cy + dist * Math.sin(angle);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
```

#### Experiment

I added some constants

```
const quadWidth = Math.PI / 2;     // area of effect PI/2 is 90 degree
const steps = radius / quadWidth; // number steps around the circle matches 1 pixel per step, 
const noiseAmpMax = 5;         // in pixels
const noiseWaveMoveSpeed = 2;  // speed of waves on circle in radians per second
const noiseWaveFreq = 16;      // how many waves per 360 deg
```

To get a understanding what they do experiment and change the numbers to see what happens.

Comment: i don't get it at all. can you explain it more clearly

Comment: I just have to say, this answer is excellent in both explanation and creepiness of the generated animation.